# connect to Node.js Https server through browser

Tags: node.js, express, certificate, client-certificates

I have a simple node.js server

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const https = require('https');
    const express = require('express');
    const server = express();
    server.get('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req);
        res.end('as'); 
    });
    https.createServer({
requestCert: true,
rejectUnauthorized: true,
key: fs.readFileSync('agent.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('agent.pem'),
ca: fs.readFileSync('agent.pem')
}, server).listen(9000);
```

What cert do i need to add to browser, so that oi would be able to connect to this server?

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, you would need to provide ssl options in order to connect to the server.

Something for a basic GET request with axios would look like the following

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const ca   = fs.readFileSync("pathtoca");
const cert = fs.readFileSync("pathtocert");
const key  = fs.readFileSync("pathtokey"); 
const secureProtocol = "TLSv1_2_method";
const url = 'https://localhost:9000';
const passphrase = "mypassphrase";

const options = { 
 secureProtocol, // protocol for secure request
 passphrase,     // passphrase for key if it's encrypted
 key,            // key used to decrypt client certificate
 cert,           // your client certificate
 ca,             // include this if you are using a ca not included on your machine's default ca chain (e.g. a self signed ca usually)
 requestCert: true        // check the server to see if it has a certificate
 rejectUnauthorized: true // if server has unauthorized certificate, abort request
}
const agent = new https.Agent(options);
const axiosOptions = { httpsAgent: agent };
axios.get(url, axiosOptions)
```

You should also be able to accomplish a similar request with `https`

```js
https.request(options) // using `options` variable listed in the previous code block
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a signed SSL-Certificate if you want to fire up an HTTPS-Server.
In case you don't care about security and just want to start it locally, you could just get rid of all the https stuff and start a normal http-Server like this

```
    const http = require('http');
    const express = require('express');
    const server = express();
    server.get('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req);
        res.end('as'); 
    });
    http.createServer(server).listen(9000);
```

(not tested though)

Comment: well... this is just an experimental server to see if thingns we need work in browsers. https is requirement. But we got it solved for temporary case. replaced CA with client cert. now client can connect.